# Convert select result to column name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `@MyTemp` that looks like this:

```
|Name |Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|Test |18:30 |15:40  |15:40    |17:30   |18:30 |08:30   |09:30  |
```

And I know I can get day in SQL Server by using

```
DECLARE @Today NVARCHAR(50) = (SELECT datename(dw,getdate()))
```

How can I get just day results in my select

```
SELECT  @Today From @MyTemp  ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT 
  CASE datename(dw,getdate())
    WHEN 'Monday'    THEN Monday
    WHEN 'Tuesday'   THEN Tuesday
    WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN Wednesday
    WHEN 'Thursday'  THEN Thursday
    WHEN 'Friday'    THEN Friday
    WHEN 'Saturday'  THEN Saturday
    WHEN 'Sunday'    THEN Sunday
  END today
  FROM @MyTemp
 WHERE Name = 'Test'
```

Sample output:

```
| TODAY |
---------
| 09:30 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1c06/91)**

Comment: . . Even more cool, you could add a computed column into the table definition and the "today" column would return the right value all the time.